# Change ul li parent color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


    <ul class="cars_menu">
        <li>Audi
            <ul>
                <li class="highlight">A4</li>
                <li>A6</li>
                <li>A3</li>
                <li>A5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Volkswagen
            <ul>
                <li>Golf IV</li>
                <li>Golf VI</li>
                <li>Golf V</li>
                <li>Jetta</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>BMW
            <ul>
                <li>E36</li>
                <li>E60</li>
                <li>E70</li>
                <li>Z4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.highlight {
    color: red;
 }
```

And my script file:

```
$( "ul.cars_menu li" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
});
```

Anyone know, how to change the color of AUDI, if I click on A4, A6 it should set the color of A4 AND AUDI to red and if for example I click on GOLF IV it needs to change of Volkswagen and GOLF IV to red and so on.

Anyone could help me with this? Appreciate, guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your jQuery in a :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('ul.cars_menu li').click(function() {
         $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
     });
 });
```

Reason for this - you need to wait for the DOM to finish loading before you can set the events on the elements further down the page...

$(document).ready event is when the DOM is finished loading & can be manipulated...

Editing to include js fiddle with some examples on how this can be done:
http://jsfiddle.net/7gdzLgam/

The answer on how to target parent elements using jquery that was the original question still applies to example above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it detect click and changes color. Thank you :). Now I will try to improve my js code to make it how i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the html code to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


    <ul class="cars_menu">
        <li>Audi</li>
        <li>
            <ul class="model">
                <li>A4</li>
                <li>A6</li>
                <li>A3</li>
                <li>A5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Volkswagen</li>
        <li>
            <ul class="model">
                <li>Golf IV</li>
                <li>Golf VI</li>
                <li>Golf V</li>
                <li>Jetta</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>BMW</li>
        <li>
            <ul class="model">
                <li>E36</li>
                <li>E60</li>
                <li>E70</li>
                <li>Z4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Jquery code to

```
$( "ul.model li" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).parent().removeClass( "highlight" );
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
    $( this ).parent().parent().prev('li').toggleClass( "highlight" );
});
```

Hope it will works!!!.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use .parent() for this.
Something like:

$( this ).parent().toggleClass( "highlight" );

Comment: Thank you for response but my code can't even find click for some reason. i am trying to click on everything, but nothing reacts at all.

Comment: Ok not sure how you want it to function but just toggleing class on parent can be done as I wrote earlier.
There are however a bunch of things to consider here. One is how you target the click event, another one that highlight will make entire class red, including it's "children" elements.
I'm not sure what you want to accomplish but I made some modifications in this jsfiddle that you can try to play around with:
http://jsfiddle.net/7gdzLgam/

Comment: Thank you, I will try to play with it a little bit more. It's very tricky.

Comment: Putting jquery in a $(document).ready is always advised, since the javascript may execute and try to attach to dom objects before they are loaded into the browser. By putting all javascript into $(document).ready, it ensures that the javascript is only run once the page has entirely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the value of the li clicked by doing

```
$( "ul.cars_menu li" ).click(function() {
    if ($( this ).text() == 'A4'){
       //change css
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM elements will not be created when the js file is downloaded. Your javascript is correct but either you need to include your

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

at the end of body tag so that it will work.

This is because when the javascript is loaded it checks for the dom element which you have specified in the js file. It will not be able to find the element since the dom is not completely created. So it just neglects it.

Or else wrap the javascript inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your code here
});
```

so that js will not be executed unless the dom elements are created.